# FaceBook Graph Api: how to get the promoted posts for an account/page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I wonder if there is an API which could return the promoted posts for a account/page?
I've already went through the API docs and find nothing helpful.

Comment: Did you finally find anything?

Comment: @scottydelta The newest facebook api like `/me/insights` with params will give back the info we need. Hope this could be helpful to you.

Comment: I am mainly looking to get the comments from all the promoted posts but ```/page_id/insights``` shows irrelevant data, can you please elaborate a little more. thanks

Comment: @scottydelta Did you find a way to achieve this?

Comment: no, this seems to be part of the FB Marketing beta program. if you are an enterprise client of FB marketing then talk to your rep, they can provide the beta API docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Promoted Posts of an Account via

```
/<VERSION>/act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives?fields=object_story_id
```

Documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative

To access this API you need ads management & ads read permissions, and user must be the admin/developer of the Application.